# Showing a Div (with calculated values) based upon options selected - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and am trying to build a simple app to teach myself.  I have the following select options which are displaying just the keys of a data object so far. What I want to do is show a value underneath the second select box for each team, which shows the value associated with the key when a first option is selected, then adds to that value when the second option selected. How do I do that in angular?
I tried {{v}} for just the first one but that didn't work, and I would still need to add the second one.

```
<div>Team 1</div>
<br> Player 1:
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem1">
    <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo">{{k}}</option>
</select>
Player 2:
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem2">
    <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo">{{k}}</option>
</select>
<!-- show value here -->
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div>Team 2</div>
<br> Player 1:
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem3">
    <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo">{{k}}</option>
</select>Player 2:
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem4">
    <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo">{{k}}</option>
</select>
<!-- show value here -->
<div ng-show="k == v">{{v}}</div>
```

Values would go under the team two boxes.

UPDATE:
This worked for me!

```
$scope.calc = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue = Number($scope.selectedItem1);
        if($scope.selectedItem2){
                $scope.calculatedValue = Number($scope.selectedItem1) + Number($scope.selectedItem2);

        }

    }

    $scope.calc2 = function() {
        $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3);
        if ($scope.selectedItem4) {

        $scope.calculatedValue2 = Number($scope.selectedItem3) + Number($scope.selectedItem4);
        };

    }

<div>Team 1</div>
    <br> Player 1:
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-change="calc()">
        <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v" >{{k}}</option>
    </select>
    Player 2:
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem2" ng-change="calc()">
        <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v">{{k}}</option>
    </select>
    <!-- show value here -->
    <p> Total Value: {{calculatedValue}} </p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>Team 2</div>
    <br> Player 1:
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem3" ng-change="calc2()">
        <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v" >{{k}}</option>
    </select>Player 2:
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem4" ng-change="calc2()">
        <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v">{{k}}</option>
    </select>
    <!-- show value here -->
    <p> Total Value: {{calculatedValue2}} </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put together a fiddle based on your example. You need to add a change event to the select forms to tell your controller to calculate the values and create a new property on the $scope which stores the calculated value, which can be bound to in the html.

HTML

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem1" ng-change="calc()">
    <option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v">{{k}}</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
// these should be set to default number values
$scope.selectedItem1 = 0;
$scope.selectedItem2 = 0;

$scope.data = {
    playerInfo : {
        a:1,
        b:2,
        c:3
    }
};

// this method will calculate the value
$scope.calc = function(){
    $scope.calculatedValue = parseFloat($scope.selectedItem1) + parseFloat($scope.selectedItem2);
}
```

One thing to note, you need to set the default values of selectedItem1 and selectedItem2 or the change event won't know how to calculate the non-numeric undefined values of the unchanged selects.

Here is a working example based on your code:
https://jsfiddle.net/gu9fm5xh/1/

Comment: Thanks that was super helpful! How would I get the result to show up immediately when the first item is selected, and then updated when the second item is selected?

Comment: Updating my code to show my solution. Any advice on how to refactor to abstract those two functions in to one would be appreciated!

Comment: You are doing a check to make sure that the second option has been filled out to avoid the NaN that comes back from the calc method. I would suggest just defaulting both of those options:

    // these should be set to default number values
    $scope.selectedItem1 = 0;
    $scope.selectedItem2 = 0;

Is there a reason those numbers can't be set to 0 by default?

Comment: I updated the fiddle with a simpler solution. I don't love having a function in the view, but without more knowledge of the rest of the code its a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

so a couple of things,

First: using ng-repeat in options is usually not they way you want to go, you want to use ng-options on the select element. But this isn't a major problem.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-options="data.displayValue for data in data.playerInfo" ng-model="selectedItem4">
```

This will show on the select "data.displayValue" which can be any property on the playerInfo object. And it will set selectedItem4 to the actual data object.

Second: In your div you are using the k and v variables that are in your ng-repeat. ng-repeat creates its own scope and the scope variables k and v are not accessible outside of your repeat and each ng-repeat uses its own k and v. If you want to use the selected values outside of the ng-repeat you need to set them to scope variable. luckily with option you can do this my setting the value field.

```
<option ng-repeat="(k,v) in data.playerInfo" ng-value="v">{{k}}</option>
```

ng-options does this for you behind the scenes. What this will do is bind your selects ng-model to the current option being shown.  so if this option is under this select then selectedItem4 will be set to the value of the option selected.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedItem4">
```

Meaning in your div if you change it to be

```
<div >{{selectedItem4}}</div>
```

This should work, a little better.